# Gunicorn timeout exception for specific urls

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn

I use Gunicorn for my python web service with NGINX.

I observe the following problem: even though I have client_max_body_size is big enough in nginx's config, I still get 502 error code when I try to upload big files. I believe that's because uploading is not finished within timeout 90 seconds set when I run my gunicorn workers.

So, my question - is it possible to specify timeout exception for some URLs in Gunicorn command line or config? For example, for file upload URL I want higher timeout and small one for other URLs. If not, what workaround could be implemented?

Thanks in advance!